Dereferencing with mongoengine
I have an AuctionDocument which reference an ItemDocument.
I want to be able to query all auctions for a selleruuid, and iterate over the results (and have access to Auction.item.auctioned for instance)
class ItemDocument(Document):
    _id = UUIDField(binary=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    auctioned = BooleanField(required=True, default=False)

class AuctionDocument(Document):
    _id = UUIDField(binary=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    item = ReferenceField(ItemDocument, required=True)
    seller = ReferenceField(CreatureDocument, required=True)

So, in DB, an Auction looks like this:
{
  "_id": "e52fae8a-2835-4f15-8303-6d3dccb445bd",
  "item": "10c18b68-7550-4eb3-aa19-c65df42c088a",
  "seller": "20671520-85fb-35ad-861a-e8ccebe1ebb9",
}

This doesn't work, but that was expected:
Auctions = AuctionDocument.objects(seller=selleruuid)

This neither, but considering the docs, it should:
Auctions = AuctionDocument.objects(seller=selleruuid).select_related()

I have this error: Trying to dereference unknown document DBRef('item', UUID('10c18b68-7550-4eb3-aa19-c65df42c088a'))
Though, the Item exists in DB:
{
  "_id": "10c18b68-7550-4eb3-aa19-c65df42c088a",
  "auctioned": true,
}

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, and I'd gladly receive some help/pointers in the right direction

Apparently, theres an issue about that: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/915
It appears it's due to the fact that I use binary=False for the UUID.
I tried with binary=True, and it works, but it makes the "reading" of the ID difficult
